# Should I place an accepted but not yet published/presented paper in my CV?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions

I was notified that my paper has been accepted for publication and presentation on November. As I'm currently applying for a Master's degree, I believe that this will increase my chances of getting accepted. However, the application deadline precedes the publication and presentation data.

Is it ethical to place it on my CV? Also, will it carry any weight during the application process, if it has not yet been published and presented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can and should list it on your CV. For conferences, even listing the date of the conference as some future date makes it pretty clear what is going on, especially in a field like CS where conferences are frequent and important.

But you would do better to mark it as "accepted for presentation at ... to be held (where) and (when).

After the conference you simply update the CV.

This is, I think, especially appropriate for a CV prepared for an academic application. It should capture the moment in time. And, yes, it will carry weight if the conference is well recognized in the field. The conference committee and reviewers have put weight and reputation behind your work.

Comment: (To the OP) I suggest that you indicate on the CV the date when it was written.