# Abstract accepted for full paper development; how to report it in a CV?

Tags: cv

My proposal for a  book chapter call for papers has been accepted, and I'm now writing the entire paper. I want to report in my CV. Is it appropriate? If yes, how can I do it? I'm thinking of creating a "work in progress" section to list it together with the wording "accepted for submission", what do you think of this solution?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between "forthcoming" and "in press"?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26024/is-there-a-difference-between-forthcoming-and-in-press)

Comment: If the connection is not clear, this question (which is very similar to your question) was recently closed as a duplicate of the above linked question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/187101/should-i-place-an-accepted-but-not-yet-published-presented-paper-in-my-cv?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a universal indicator here. For articles, the only tag I've seen that carries any weight is "[in press]", which generally indicates that the article has been accepted and is being readied for submission. The actual publication date (in the future) would be indicated in the reference itself.

As such, given that your CFP response was accepted, I would indicate that in somewhat long form... "[abstract accepted, chapter in preparation]". Provide enough context that the reader knows what you're saying.